# Rails: Migrations altering schema.rb from origin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, schema, database-migration

Sometimes when running migrations (via `rake db:migrate`) after fetching and merging new commits my `schema.rb` file gets changed from what is on `origin`. Here's a partial diff:

```
@@ -103,15 +103,15 @@ ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170927104005) do
   add_index "conversions", ["user_id"], name: "index_conversions_on_user_id", using: :btree

   create_table "delayed_jobs", force: :cascade do |t|
-    t.integer  "priority",   default: 0, null: false
-    t.integer  "attempts",   default: 0, null: false
-    t.text     "handler",                null: false
+    t.integer  "priority",               default: 0, null: false
+    t.integer  "attempts",               default: 0, null: false
+    t.text     "handler",                            null: false
     t.text     "last_error"
     t.datetime "run_at"
     t.datetime "locked_at"
     t.datetime "failed_at"
-    t.string   "locked_by"
-    t.string   "queue"
+    t.string   "locked_by",  limit: 255
+    t.string   "queue",      limit: 255
     t.datetime "created_at"
     t.datetime "updated_at"
   end
```

After `rake db:migrate` the `schema.rb` is the only file with changes. I really don't want to commit these back to the repo as they will only create issues for other developers.

Anyone know what's going on and how to fix or back out of this?

Thanks!

Comment: are you all using the same setup? seems like someone might be on different rails versions. or if you have a linter/beautifier that runs on save.

Comment: all on same version of Rails & Ruby (they're specified in codebase) but there's a chance PostgreSQL versions may differ though probably only by x (9.6.x)